# AngularJS bootstrap twitter hover on link stay after click even when it is not hover anymore

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When i move cursor on link it shows with hover style and it's good.
When i move cursor back from link hover disappear and it's good.

But when i click on link hover looks stay even if i move cursor back. Why? What am i doing wrong? How to solve that?

I have never had this problem when using only bootstrap without AngularJS.

Page: http://wladyka.eu/d/#/

Demonstration of problem:
[image]

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584392/bootstraps-tooltip-doesnt-disappear-after-button-click-mouseleave

Answer (score 2):

You need to override bootsrap :focus pseudo class for `.btn-link`:

```
.navbar-default .btn-link:focus {
    color: #777;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: But why is it happening? It is not standard behavior of this framework :) What cause this problem? I want to also understand this :)

Comment: Actually this is built-in Bootsrtap styles for `btn-link` class: `.navbar-default .btn-link:hover, .navbar-default .btn-link:focus {color: #333;}`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to overwrite the css for the `:active` and the `:focus` state of the button

Answer (score 1):

Actually your anchor is focused you need to remove it
Can be acheive it by :-

```
$("#your_id").mouseup(function(){
    $(this).blur();
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6nyLxkd/)