# Bootstrap's tooltip doesn't disappear after button click & mouseleave

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a problem with bootstrap's tooltip : When I click on a button, tooltip stays even if is the cursor is outside of the button. I have looked into the manual - [Bootstrap's tooltip](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#four-directions) and if I'm clicking on the buttons, I see the same problem. Is there any solution to fix this? Just tried in latest FF, IE.

Comment: It's not working in link in my question too, let's look there. There is the same problem.

Answer (score 319, accepted):

This is because `trigger` is not set. The default value for trigger is `'hover focus'`, thus the tooltip stay visible after a button is clicked, until another button is clicked, because the button is `focused`.

So all you have to do is to define `trigger` as `'hover'` only. Below the same example you have linked to without persisting tooltips after a button is clicked :

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger : 'hover'
})
```

the doc example in a fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vdzvvg6o/**

Comment: Thank you David, that really works. I misunderstood trigger option for tooltip in last, now I'm right.

Comment: @SilentCry Just keep in mind who you are targeting, triggering a "hover" might not always be easy/common.

Comment: @phk - can you give an example of what you mean or have in mind?

Comment: @davidkonrad Mobile platforms, blind users. Might also explain why they set  'hover focus' as the default.

Comment: @phk, bootstrap has a general problem by not being mobile-first, regarding blind people we should use aria-attributes.  There is BTW a great tool for testing for usability developed for the canadian authorities with several "levels" you can fulfill -> **http://achecker.ca/checker/index.php** my country does not have these standards, but it is worth keeping up to them anyway.

Comment: You might want to have a look at Karmonik Cola's answer below. It keeps showing the tooltip on focus.

Comment: Thanks. I hate these kind of annoying, time consuming "little" things.. This should be the default behaviour..

Comment: Thanks David. It worked for me. Actually the click was happening on some browsers and OS. This fix made to behave same everywhere.

Comment: Could have saved a couple of hours and unnecessary code if I had read this first.  Thanks for posting!

Comment: My problem was that the data-trigger attribute was set on my element, this answer clued me in to be able to see it

Comment: What should we do for mobile devices? I have problem with it. It won't disappear after click on button. I should tap somewhere to disappear.

Comment: Can we combine click trigger while closing on mouse out?

Comment: Gracia mate. I was scratching my head trying to debug this & I noticed the tooltip flickering when I was inspecting the page in the browser & then a google search landed me here. Your answer gave me something to try in `Angular` & I used `triggers='hover'` & voila, everything was running like a frog.

Comment: Thank you, @davidkonrad! When I click in my link the tooltip now is hiding correctly, but do not show again if I put the mouse over the link again. FIXED: My script are erasing the content of the attribute "data-original-title" after a postback.

Comment: The best solution for me would be to find a way to change the default trigger. Having to add this settings is not a good solution because we would need to update the code everywhere we call `.tooltip()` and make sure all developers never forget to add this setting in the future. I'm telling you, they will.

Answer (score 88):

I know over a year old, but I couldn't get this to work with any examples here. I've had to use the following:

```
$('[rel="tooltip"]').on('click', function () {
    $(this).tooltip('hide')
})
```

This also shows the tooltip again upon hover.

Comment: This needs to be the accepted answer and also should be implemented into the bootstrap codebase.

Comment: This was extremely helpful for bootstrap tooltips placed on buttons with a trigger of 'hover' that cause asynchronous postbacks (i.e. display modal panels). Without this, the postback from the button press causes the tooltip to get "stuck" and never disappear.

Comment: In my case, I was disabling the submit button while an ajax action was performed. While the ajax process was running, the tooltip would remain since the button was disabled. Once the ajax process completed, the button would become "available" again. Hovering on and then off of the button would dismiss the tooltip. Nitai's solution fixed everything. The tooltip now hides upon click and still works on hover once the button becomes active again.

Comment: I agree with @kjdion84 . I have been struggling until I found this

Comment: This is the answer.

Answer (score 17):

### With Bootstrap 5

Tooltips are now initialized in plain/vanilla Javascript. Because I only saw JQuery options here, let me post the VERY SIMPLE and straightforward way in plain JS :

```
//Initialize bootstrap tooltips
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'));
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map( function(tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
  trigger : 'hover'
  });
});
```

You only need to add the "{trigger : 'hover'}" object as an option of bootstrap.Tooltip(element, options).

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/#usage

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: not working, still randomly some hover text doesn't hide after mouseleave

Answer (score 16):

Hi i have little solution for this issue. When other solutions doesn't work just try this one:

```
$('body').tooltip({
        selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
    }).on('click mousedown mouseup', '[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])', function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])').tooltip('destroy');
    });
```

This is solution for drag and drop too.
So i hope this help someone :)

Comment: I was having the problem only with Telerik Kendo grid buttons. When I clicked one, the tooltiip would not hide.  This solved it!

Comment: this worked for me when I used dispose instead of destroy

Comment: this worked for me when I used dispose instead of destroy

Comment: thanks, I have to add some lines because 'destroy' gives me an error:  $('body').tooltip({
        selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])',
        trigger: 'hover',
        container: 'body'
    }).on('click mousedown mouseup', '[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])', function () {
        var element = $(this);
        var tooltip = $(element).attr('aria-describedby');
        $(tooltip).remove();
    });

Answer (score 14):

This is also achievable in the HTML by adding the following:

```
 data-trigger="hover"

 <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-trigger="hover" title="To re-enable scanning, click here">Text</button>
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work and tooltip is still stuck.

Comment: Tnx, only solution that worked for me, because i call toogleTooltip method  on (mouseover)

Comment: Worked for me. (I have just Bootstrap 4 and jQuery)

Comment: With Bootstrap 5 attribute name changed. data-bs-trigger="hover" works fine.

Answer (score 13):

In my case the issue was reproduced only in Internet Explorer: no matter which element(input, div etc...) has tooltip- if clicked- tooltip remains shown.

found some solutions on web that recommends .hide() that tooltip on elements Click event- but it is bad idea- hovering back to the same element - keeps it hidden...
in my case

```
$('.myToolTippedElement').on('click', function () {
    $(this).blur()
})
```

made all the magic!!!- where .myToolTippedElement is the element that have a tooltip ofCourse...

Comment: Works for me too, and has the advantage over the accepted solution of keeping displaying the tooltip on focus.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 8):

in angular 7 with bootstrap 4 and jquery I found this and it works fine. I used dispose because it destroys does not hide the tooltip.

```
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
      trigger: 'hover'
    });
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('mouseleave', function () {
      $(this).tooltip('dispose');
    });
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('click', function () {
      $(this).tooltip('dispose');
    });
   }
```

Comment: Take note that if the tooltip is disposed rather than hidden, it will never come back upon re-hovering the element in question.

Answer (score 6):

**Working Solution**

```
$(document).on("click",function()
    {
    setTimeout(function()
    {

  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');

},500);    // Hides tooltip in 500 milliseconds
    });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: @Adam I wasn't able to find any working solutions on the forums to hide a tooltip after clicking any <a>, <button> or other elements which have button functionality or appearance attached to them.

Comment: yeah I also found nothing worked until I added a timeout (I just used 10millis)

Answer (score 5):

The way I fixed this issue was by removing the tooltip in the click event function using the following code:

```
$("#myButton").on("click", function() {
    $("div[role=tooltip]").remove();
});
```

Comment: can You ble get the tooltip again on hover?

Comment: @Vishnu: Yes. I now use both of these (the ONLY consistent solution I've found for this issue): $(".btn").on("click", function () {
            $("div[role=tooltip]").remove();
         });
         $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
            trigger: 'hover'
         })

Answer (score 4):

Also you can add:

```
onclick="this.blur()"
```

Comment: how this is different from what Kamornik Cola has proposed (except for implementation without jQuery)? I suggest to add some explanation for the answer to be helpful. Best regards

Answer (score 3):

Try using `rel="tooltip"` instead of `data-toggle="tooltip"` which worked in my case. I was using  `data-toggle="tooltip"` and also set the trigger condition as hover which didn't work in my case. When I changed my data selector, it worked.

**HTML Code:**

```
<button id="submit-btn" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" rel="tooltip" title="Click to submit this form">Submit</button>
```

**JS Code**
//Tooltip
$('.btn').tooltip({
trigger: 'hover'
});

This will definitely remove the stuck tooltip.

Answer (score 3):

David's answer above helped to fix my problem.
I had both hover and click event on the button. Firefox on MAC did behave as I wanted. That is, show tooltip when hover, do not show tooltip for click.
On other browsers and OS, When I click, the tooltip appear and stay as show. Even if i move the mouse to other buttons for hover.
This is what I had:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({placement: 'right', html: true});
```

This is the fix:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({placement: 'right', html: true, trigger: 'hover'});
```

Answer (score 2):

If nothing works, try this.
*execute when clicked on a button or any element that has the tooltip.

```
let tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName("tooltip");
tooltip[0].parentNode.removeChild(tooltip[0]);
```

Comment: Tried this and it work. Only problem is when added on a function and called for the second time. Resolved it by removing all tooltip child using `$.each`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below method to hide tooltip on *mouseleave*, As below:

```
jQuery("body").on("mouseleave", ".has-tooltip", function(){
    jQuery(this).blur();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use this way for old versions because the accepted answer didn't worked for me and I wrote this code for my self and its work well.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', "[aria-describedby]", function() {
    $("[aria-describedby]").tooltip('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To me, works only when I put this code. P.S.: I'm using Bootstrap 4.

```js
$("body").tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle=tooltip]',
    trigger: 'hover'
}).on('click mousedown mouseup', '[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])', function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])').tooltip('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
  animated: 'fade',
  placement: 'bottom',
  trigger: 'click'
});

$('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});

$('body').click(function(){
  $('a[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a4WwQ/2020/)

I tried most of the solutions given in previous answers, but none of them worked for me.

Comment: Thanks. This works fine for me.
But how can we additional add hover? Open tooltip through hover?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is in DataTable. Below code works for me.

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        targets: 0, data: "id", 
        render: function (data, type, full, meta) {
            return '<a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Pending" data-container="body"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></a>';
        }
    }
 ],
drawCallback: function() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('click', function () {
        $(this).tooltip('hide');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with Bootstrap 4 on iPhone with Safari.

On PC/Desktop, the tooltip is working great.
But when looking on an iPhone with iOS 14, after click / tap on a button, the tooltip remained visible. Also when hiding the layer.

For me, adding this code solved the issue on iPhone:

```
jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
    trigger : 'hover'
}); 

jQuery('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on("click", function () {
    $(this).tooltip("hide");
});
```

Comment: This happens with me on MacOS Chrome and your answer solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the multiple solutions/suggestions above doesn't work. I put the data-bs-* options in a nested span tag after the button tag and it works after button clicked. I may assume  that other tags than span should works as well but i didn't try after I got it working.

```
<div>
 <button type="button">
  <span data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top">Button Name</span>
 </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

clear trigger and reproducing the default behavior

```
const el = document.getElementById('my-tooltip-el');
const tooltip = new bootstrap.Tooltip(el, {
    trigger: ''
});

el.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
    tooltip.show();
})
el.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    setTimeout(() => tooltip.hide(), 150)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can hide all Bootstrap's tooltips by simply deleting the created HTML elements to show them.

##### When you hover over an element with a tooltip, Bootstrap create new HTML elements, and normally delete them when hovering out.

[image]

#### Bootstrap 5

```
for (const item of document.querySelectorAll('.bs-tooltip-auto')) {
    item.remove();
}
```

#### Bootstrap 4

```
$('.tooltip.show').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

For me was important had **"hover focus"**, but solutions that was offer not work for me with **"drag and drop"** problem: when you click on element and in this time leave mouse cursor and mouse up not in element area, in this case i still have tooltip.

```js
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').mouseleave(function() {
  this.tooltip('hide');
});
```

This solution work with focus and "drag and drop" problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Some part of this issue might be the result of DOM changes that occur while the "hover" state is in force.

I've got my tooltip initiation set like this (copied from the Bootstrap docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/tooltips/)

```
    var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
    var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
      return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl, {
        container: 'body',
        trigger : 'hover'          
      })
    })
```

It uses that '[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]' selector, they all work, but some like to stay onscreen after the button that invokes it is clicked, specifically if the result of the click wipes out the button that it was shown for.

My solution here is a slightly modified version of another answer here from 2016.... to target anything that matches that same [data-bs-toggle="tooltip"] (Bootstrap 5.1) selector.

As I mentioned above, I think it should be noted that a Bootstrap tooltip can only be properly initiated and work as expected if nothing changes on the DOM while it is showing (typically due to other AJAX results being displayed).
If, for instance, the tooltip is showing **while** the DIV that contains it shifts down by 10px due to some other DOM change, it sticks (and sometimes even "ghosts" itself).  Just a thought.  That was partly causing the problem I had.

I made sure that any element with a tooltip on it could not fire a mouse-over (hover) event, until the entire DOM had finished shifting following AJAX output.

I also added this following bit just after the above initiation.

```
    $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').on('click', function () {
        $(this).tooltip('hide')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The tooltip was not being cleared on route change, following solution helped me.

```
private popoverInstance: Popover | null = null;
this.popoverInstance = new Popover(this.elementRef.nativeElement, {
     trigger: this.trigger,
     html: true,
     placement: this.placement ? this.placement : this.place,
     content: el,
     customClass: popoverClass,
});

ngOnDestroy(): void {
    if (this.popoverInstance) {
      this.popoverInstance.dispose(); // Dispose the popover when the directive is destroyed
      this.popoverInstance = null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer to hide all of them when clicking on any tooltip. Otherwise, different issues arise while hide one. If another tooltip is clicked, it will already appear again.

```
$('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').on('click', function(e) {        
    $('.tooltip').hide();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm using bootstrap tooltip in cycle.js and none of the above worked for me.

I had to do this:

```
return button( selector + '.btn.btn-sm', 
             {
               hook: {
                 destroy: tooltipOff,
                 insert:  toggleTooltipOn,
               },
....

function toggleTooltipOn(vnode){
  setupJQuery();  
  jQuery[0].$( vnode.elm )
    .tooltip({container:'body', trigger: 'hover');
//container:body is to help tooltips not wiggle on hover
//trigger:hover is to only trigger on hover, not on click
}

function tooltipOff( vnode ){
  setupJQuery();      
  jQuery[0].$( vnode.elm ).tooltip('hide');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#save').tooltip({
            trigger : 'hover'
        }) ;

});
```

I was disabling save button dynamically then problem was.

Comment: Here  save is id of my button

Answer (score -1):

In my case for this was the fix:

```
beforeDestroyingElement() {    
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip('hide');
}
```

I wasn't obeying this rule from Bootstrap docs:

> Tooltips must be hidden before their corresponding elements have been removed from the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

If someone want's to setup a tooltip which will show for some time after click, here is how I did:

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({
trigger : 'click'})  

$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function () {
$(this).tooltip('hide')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Using a forced blur() has the potention to reduce the user experience. I wouldn't do that. I found that removing the "data-original-title" as well as removing the attributes "data-toggle" and "title" worked for me.

```
    $(id).tooltip('hide');
    $(id).removeAttr("data-toggle");
    $(id).removeAttr("data-original-title");
    $(id).removeAttr("title");
```

Answer (score -1):

Using delegation to make it ajax friendly,

```
// if you're not using turbolinks, then you can remove this parent wrapper
$(document).on('turbolinks:load'), function() {  
  // enable tooltip with delegation to allow ajax pages to keep tooltip enabled
  $('body').tooltip({
    select: "[data-toggle='tooltip']"
  });

  // remove old tooltip from sticking on the page when calling ajax with turbolinks
  $('body').on('click', "[data-toggle='tooltip']", function() {
    $(this).tooltip('dispose');
  });
});
```