# Twitter Bootstrap Tooltip: flickers on mouse down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am dealing with some weird behavior of bootstrap's tooltip.

**Versions of ASP.Net and Bootstrap:**

ASP.Net 4.5

Boostrap 3.0.0

**Scenario:**

I'm working on my webapp in which I need to use Bootstrap tooltip on button. Every thing is working fine but I feel that tooltip is flickering when my mouse down event is fired. Here is the gif:

[image]

My question is how I prevent this flickering of tooltip on mouse down event in my ASP.Net webapp using jquery or whatever css hint?

What I've tried before is

[Github ref#1](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3075#issuecomment-363461060)
[Github ref#2](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/3075#issuecomment-370957308)

`.tooltip { pointer-events: none; }`
`container="body`

but none of them worked in my case. Also I've share here my `Bundle.config` file in which you can see the alignment of my bootstrap and custom css files.

```
<bundles version="1.0">
    <styleBundle path="~/Content/css">
        <include path="~/Content/bootstrap.css" />
        <include path="~/Content/chosen.css" />
        <include path="~/Content/Site.css" />
        <include path="~/Content/font-awesome.css" />
        <include path="~/Content/AutoComplete.css" />
        <include path="~/Content/GridView.css" />
        <include path="~/Content/custom.css" />
    </styleBundle>
</bundles>
```

in my site master page I put below jquery in the end of my page:

`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip({ container: 'body' });`

and put this css in my custom css file

`.tooltip { pointer-events: none !important; }
.popover { pointer-events: none !important; }`

Now please tell me what I'm doing wrong or What is the right way to prevent this flickering on mouse down event.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar odd behavior from Bootstrap in a Visual Studio ASP.NET application. If Bootstrap was installed as part of your project (it probably was), try removing the NuGet package and reinstalling it. Whilst you do that, I recommend upgrading Bootstrap to version 3.3.7 or newer.

Comment: ok I've upgrade my bootstrap version 3.0.0 to 3.3.7 but issue is still occurs. what is your bootstrap version in which you have solve this problem?

Comment: Unless you're looking for backward browser compatibility, upgrade to version 4.1. Did you make sure you uninstall the NuGet package and then reinstall, rather than upgrade? Also, ensure to clear your browser cache between the bootstrap upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

[This is resolved from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584392/bootstraps-tooltip-doesnt-disappear-after-button-click-mouseleave/43366838#43366838)

I put below code in my master page and this solve my problem.

```
$('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])',
    trigger: 'hover',
    container: 'body'
}).on('click mousedown mouseup', '[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])', function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"], [title]:not([data-toggle="popover"])').tooltip('destroy');
});
```